# Typescript: Define for JSON nested object

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, nested

I have a nested json object and define a interface for it

```
interface Menu {
    [key: string]: string[] | Menu;
}

const menuOnlyForRoles: Menu = {
    site: {
        only: [],
        category: {
            only: ['manager', 'head', 'lead'],
        },
        'floor-section': {
            only: ['head', 'lead'],
        },
    },
};
```

But when I use it. It appear a warning.

```
const menuPermissionForKey = menuOnlyForRoles.site || { only: [] };
const rolesCanAccessMenu= menuPermissionForKey.only || [];
                                               ▔▔▔▔
     any
     Property 'only' does not exist on type 'Menu | string[]'.
       Property 'only' does not exist on type 'string[]'
```

What did I do wrong or missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't do anything wrong per se. TypeScript just cannot infer whether your `menuPermissionForKey` is a `Menu` object or a `string` array.

Ideally, you'd define your `Menu` type more strictly. Barring that, you can create a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates):

```
interface Menu {
    [key: string]: string[] | Menu;
}

const menuOnlyForRoles: Menu = {
    site: {
        only: [],
        category: {
            only: ['manager', 'head', 'lead'],
        },
        'floor-section': {
            only: ['head', 'lead'],
        },
    },
};

function isMenu(data: Menu | string[]): data is Menu {
    return !Array.isArray(data);
}

const menuPermissionForKey = menuOnlyForRoles.site || { only: [] };
const rolesCanAccessMenu= isMenu(menuPermissionForKey)
                              ? menuPermissionForKey.only || []
                              : [];
```

<sup>[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIRAV2QbwFDKHIDaA1hAJ4BcyAzmFKAOYC6N9jITxLyAPmgyYA3HgC+ePAgD2IesgC2QgPIgANhQBi0qACVpaiLRrosyALy4CRWsEg18RJ8lkaaPADTXnyBHEhMOtRWPj6uwcQA5ApwIHBM0JEeyJEAFhBwACZJKYZZkSxeochiRaGRMGrSOgC0tBAIYMCykQ7exS7qEWkZ2cmRedmF7U6l7WNiongwmCCNzSDIwLSmmAAUmf5wJkL8dAzMPACUNJtgcEu0gmaOyFAQYJhQiwCEAIJQUHAUAHTLH18KBstkdRBIpLJ5EosAAFaAKZa2WTaKAAaUoFkUKi6KP0hloP1skH4AhwnTcJF4kwhcjAdwMRgAwrE3ggkLQVkJLMtVmtoZg4VAERyFij0RQjsgAPxY2HwxGinTin7hEmU5DuFjCIA)</sup>

---

Alternatively, if you're dealing with static data that is known at compile-time, you can use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions), optionally with the [`satisfies` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator) to enforce type-checking at edit time:

```
interface Menu {
    [key: string]: readonly string[] | Menu;
}

const menuOnlyForRoles = {
    site: {
        only: [],
        category: {
            only: ['manager', 'head', 'lead'],
        },
        'floor-section': {
            only: ['head', 'lead'],
        },
    },
} as const satisfies Menu;

const menuPermissionForKey = menuOnlyForRoles.site || { only: [] };
const rolesCanAccessMenu = menuPermissionForKey.only || [];
```

<sup>[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIRAV2QbwFDKHIDaA1hAJ4BcyAzmFKAOYC6NUEcAJgPYgA2FOg2bEWyAD5oMmANx4AvnjwI+9ZAFsZAeQEUAYjygAlHvwi1kAXlwEitYJBr4ir5H0E0xAGjtvkCHCQTEbUtv7+HmHEAOQacCBwTNAx3sgxABacXKnp5twxLL4RyArFETEw-DxGALS0EAhgwHwxzn4l7npemdm5Mfk5RR2uZR1jCshwlqog6rRBwLQwwBbSWPIqamCaMgAK0BpLDnyGUADSlNa7WLqCZ6bmtAB0DpCSUjhdniTiCvKzdRQMwWADCCQAgggkLRaOgsDYtFgDlAjrCWiAzpcKM8oh9frIgA)</sup>